# How to select Telerik MVC tab in Javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

How to select Telerik MVC tab in Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {        

        var tabstrip = $("#tabERHC").data("tTabStrip");            
        var item = $(".t-item", tabstrip.element)[0];
        tabstrip.select(item);
    });
```

The above code is not selecting the tab

Comment: there are a bunch of options here in the Client API section for selecting the tab.. Maybe one will work for you http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-tabstrip-client-api-and-events.html

Comment: yes i tried it is not working.  alert(tabstrip)  i am getting "undefined" vlaues

Comment: you'd have to show us the rest of your view code if you want us to figure out why it's undefined

Comment: ok,  i am binding tabstrip as @Html.Telerik().TabStrip().Name("tabERHC").Items(tabstrip => { tabstrip.Add().Text("Conversion Status").LoadContentFrom("Conversion", "ConfigFile"); tabstrip.Add().Text("Effectivity").LoadContentFrom("Effectivity", "ConfigFile").Selected(true); })

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the index of tab:

```
var tabstrip = $("#tabERHC").data("tTabStrip");
$.each(tabStrip.items(), function(i, el) {
    if($(el).hasClass("t-item")) {
        tabStrip.select(i);
        return false;
    }
});
```

I think I figured that you need to focus tab on first tab with class `t-item`. Is that correct?